# Funcion que retorna un string cambia las variables donde se guardaron antes el retorno de la funcion

Tags: c++

estoy testeando cosas de opengl en c++, la cosa es que cree una clase `File` con funciones static para usarlas en distintas partes del codigo.

```cpp
/* utils.hpp */
class File {
    public:
        static std::string Read(std::string path);
};
```

```cpp
/* utils.cpp */
std::string File::Read (std::string path) {
    std::string content = "";
    std::ifstream file (path, std::ios::binary);
    if (file) {
        /* move the pointer to the end and resize the content string */  
        file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        content.resize(file.tellg());

        /* move the pointer to the beginning and read the content */
        file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        file.read(&content[0], content.size());
    }

    /* Close the handle file and return the content */
    file.close();
    return content;
}
```

Mi problema es que al intentar leer los archivos donde guardo el codigo de los shader tengo que llamar a `File::Read()` 2 veces, la primera para el vertex y la segunda para el fragment shader y guardo los valores en distintas variables pero las 2 variables terminan con el valor osea el ultimo valor que retorno la funcion.

```cpp
/* Get the source code of the fragment and vertex shaders */
// testFile1.txt = "test 1"
// testFile2.txt = "test 2"

const char* vertexSource   = File::Read("textFile1.txt").c_str(); // vertexSource   = "test 2"
const char* fragmentSource = File::Read("textFile2.txt").c_str(); // fragmentSource = "test 2"

std::cout << vertexSource << std::endl;
std::cout << fragmentSource << std::endl;
```

salida del programa:

```sh
~$ mingw32-make -s
~$ ./bin/build/main.exe
test 2
test 2
~$
```

Alguien sabe que podria estar pasando. Muchas gracias

Comment: Tienes que guardar el string en una variable, y por aparte puedes tomar el puntero al string que guardan. De la forma en la que lo haces estas tomando los datos de un temporal, que sera destruido inmediatamente. "*pero las 2 variables terminan con el valor la ultima llamada a la funcion.*" Puedes detallar un poco mas a que te refieres con esto? Ambos apuntan al mismo lugar? Ambos contienen el mismo texto? Procura que lo que publiques sea [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Pablochaches, ya edite un poco la pregunta, ojala se entienda mejor. repesto a lo primero te refieres que guarde lo que retorna la funcion en una variable `std::string` y despues llamar a el metodo `c_str()`? la verdad no entiendo a que te refieres con un temporal

Comment: Miralo asi. Llamas a `File::Read`, y este te retorna un string. A este string se le llama el metodo `c_str()`, y te quedas con un puntero a los contenidos. Luego como no asignaste el string a nadie, este se destruye, efectivamente borrando los contenidos a los que recien tomaste un puntero. Como tienes punteros a memoria que ya fue liberada, estas incurriendo en comportamiento indefinido, asi que todo puede pasar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te has encontrado con lo que se conoce como "[*comportamiento indefinido*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido)" (CI). Cuando el compilador se encuentra con un CI puede tomar decisiones bizarras<sup>1</sup> como hacer que tu código no funcione, funcione de manera extraña (como es tu caso) o algunas personas creen que puede [invocar demonios en tus fosas nasales](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nasal_demon).

#### ¿Comportamiento indefinido? ¿¡Dónde!?

El CI en tu código está concretamente aquí:

```
/* utils.cpp */
std::string File::Read (std::string path) {
    std::string content = "";
//              ~~~~~~~ <---- Variable local.
    return content;
//  ~~~~~~ <---- Devolver una variable local.
}

const char* vertexSource   = File::Read("textFile1.txt").c_str();
//             Obtiene datos de un objeto temporal ----> ~~~~~~~
const char* fragmentSource = File::Read("textFile2.txt").c_str();
//             Obtiene datos de un objeto temporal ----> ~~~~~~~
```

#### ¿Comportamiento indefinido? ¿¡Por qué!?

Lo está pasando exactamente para dar lugar al CI es lo siguiente:

1. Creas una variable local al ámbito de la función `Read`.

   1. Las variables son eliminadas en el momento en que se alcanza el final de su ámbito, es decir, en la llave de cierre (`}`).
2. Rellenas la variable local con datos.
3. Devuelves la variable local en una instrucción `return`.
4. La instrucción `return` sale del ámbito de la función, **se llama el destructor de la variable local**.
5. Se invoca el constructor de copia de `std::string` usando la variable local como origen de la copia. **Comportamiento indefinido**, estamos copiando un dato que ha sido borrado.
6. Se obtiene el puntero interno al objeto temporal creado en el paso anterior y se guarda dicho puntero en otra variable. Acto seguido se destruye el objeto temporal.
7. Se imprime el contenido apuntado por el puntero del punto anterior. **Comportamiento indefinido**, estamos accediendo a un dato que ha sido borrado.

#### ¿Qué hago para solucionarlo?

Hay dos comportamientos indefinidos que esquivar, puede hacerse de varias maneras:

1. Esquiva esos dos CI por separado:

   - **Actualiza a un compilador C++17**: El estándar del lenguaje a partir de C++17 garantiza la optimización del valor de retorno (OVR, en inglés RVA *return value optimization*), la OVR se da cuando el compilador detecta que un objeto de un ámbito va a ser devuelto fuera de dicho ámbito, en ese caso construye el objeto directamente en el ámbito externo, lo cuál soluciona el CI5.
   - **No uses `string::c_str()` sobre un temporal**: Alarga la vida del temporal o crea una copia, pero no deberías leer la memoria interna de un objeto temporal:

     ```
     const std::string &v = File::Read("textFile1.txt"); // Alarga la vida del temporal.
     const std::string f = File::Read("textFile2.txt");  // Copia el temporal.
     const char* vertexSource   = v.c_str();
     const char* fragmentSource = f.c_str();
     ```

     Esto soluciona el CI7, pero los punteros `vertexSource` y `fragmentSource` serán válidos sólo mientras los objetos `v` y `f` sigan vivos.
2. Esquívalos juntos:

   - **Cambia la función para recibir una cadena en la que copiar los datos**:

     ```
     void Read_Into(const std::string &file, std::string &destination)
     {
          if (std::ifstream i{file}) // Si 'file' falla al abrirse, no entra en el if.
          {
              using iterator = std::istream_iterator<char>;
              // Copiamos con iteradores, no hace falta 'seekg'.
              std::copy(iterator(i), iterator(), std::back_inserter(destination));
          }
          // El archivo se cierra en el destructor, no hace falta 'close'.
     }

     std::string v, f;
     Read_Into("textFile1.txt", v);
     Read_Into("textFile2.txt", f);
     const char* vertexSource   = v.c_str();
     const char* fragmentSource = f.c_str();
     ```

     Al pertenecer `destination` a un ámbito externo, evitas el CI5 y el CI7.

---

<sup>1</sup>[Bizarro, ra](https://dle.rae.es/bizarro):  Del it. *bizzarro* 'iracundo'. adj. valiente (‖ arriesgado).

Comment: Muchas gracias, decidí alargar el temporal para que el código al final se vea un poco mas limpio (al menos para mi). Soy mas usuario de python y pensé que podría concatenar instrucciones a lo loco y funcionaria igual que en python jajaja. Muchas gracias